# What happened to the files that were supposed to be installed to / for Ubuntu 16.4.3 LTS Server?

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation

I was previouly attempting to use Ubuntu 16.4.2 LTS Desktop on my server as the server OS and decided it was finally time to actually use Ubuntu Server 16.4.3 LTS instead, so I thought I could cheat and just delete the previous / partition. Then recreate /, since erasing it was taking a very long time. However, after what appears to be a successful installation of Ubuntu Server 16.4.3 LTS on it actually doesn't have any files on / after I do an ls -l, even if the df -h command says 1.8 G is being used. Can someone help or explain.

Comment: i'm confused.  to go from 16.04.2 to 16.04.3 I'd just `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, and to go from desktop to server I'd just disable gui from running (delete if you need the space) as the difference between desktop & server is only packages installed by default.  as for you where-is problem; a 'blkid' & copy of '/etc/fstab' to see what you've done..

Comment: That's just it though. There's nothing on /, so where would I find /etc/fstab?

Comment: `lsblk`(list block devices)  .. if its running a / has to be there. i get the feeling you're not using actual hardware, but a vm (where I can't help). the next thought is permissions but it doesn't add up...

Comment: Also, I didn't know you could just disable the GUI and delete it, but I was having issues with installing Nagios, LAMP, and DNS with the desktop version that didn't seem to be able to be fixed, so I decided to reinstall. Especially, since any answers I would have found as to how to fix these issues on other sites would have been spam answers and ask ubuntu probably couldn't have helped. Sorry though apparently, this was not least obstructive although pretty close considering I kept all the other partitions.

Comment: I tried to use the blkid command that you reminded me about to edit the /etc/fstab, but it didn't help because the output of / from the blkid command is already the same as what's in the /etc/fstab file. However, it didn't appear as though any of the other possible necessary entries for the other partitions were in the file, so what should I do?

Comment: if not there; add them.  `lsblk` will provide UUIDs (which are generally better than /dev/sda?), but if you use(d) encryption or lvm it can be a little different..   you can test with `mount` commands before adding them to your fstab (file system table), or umount/edit/mount without reboots but do whatever you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

On any disk partition, the file system has a reserved spaced used by the [File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table). This is the index used by the file system in order to organise file tree, inode and others files information.

More big is the hard drive, more bit is the File Allocation Table, that may take few Gigabit with the current hard drive size.